# Problema Espacio Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Buen día , estoy diseñando una pagina web para un proyecto de la facultad en el cual se puede consultar sobre materias, temas ,etc.

Estoy utilizando `Bootstrap` para poder modelar la página, pero estoy teniendo un problema. El `footer`, la parte que dice `@Copyright` y hora , se me posiciona en la mitad de la pantalla, cuando en realidad deseo que se ubique al final de todo.

Una teoría que tengo es que el `main` no tenga el tamaño suficiente como para que el `footer` este en el lugar correcto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Principal.css">
  <title>Principal</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container text-center border-bottom border-danger mt-2">
      <h3 class="header mt-1">Rodrigo Gonzalez Arias</h3>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="Container">
      <div class="container row border rounded border-danger boton">
        <div>
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/70/000000/java-coffee-cup-logo.png" alt="Logo">
          <a href="" class="ml-3">Programación</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container row border rounded border-danger boton">
        <div>
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/70/000000/networking-manager.png" alt="Logo">
          <a href="" class="ml-3">Redes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container row border rounded border-danger boton">
        <div>
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/70/000000/statistics.png" alt="Logo">
          <a href="" class="ml-3">Analisis</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="container row">
      <h3 class="col-4" style="font-size: 11px">Hora : 12:02:24</h3>
      <h3 class="col-8" style="font-size: 10px">@Copyright Universidad de Belgrano</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap tienen clases específicas para indicar posicionamiento](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/). Dichas clases se pueden aplicar a los elementos para posicionarlos de manera fija o absoluta y en diferentes lugares de la pantalla.

En particular tienes la clase `fixed-bottom` que (traducción mía):

> Posiciona un elemento en la parte inferior de la pantalla, de esquina a esquina. Asegúrate de entender las ramificaciones de usar posición `fixed` en tu proyecto, puede necesitar de CSS adicional.

Entonces puedes usar la clase `.fixed-bottom` en el `footer` para que se quede pegado a la parte  inferior de la página. Aquí puedes ver tu código tan sólo añadiendo esa clase:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Principal.css">
  <title>Principal</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container text-center border-bottom border-danger mt-2">
      <h3 class="header mt-1">Rodrigo Gonzalez Arias</h3>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="Container">
      <div class="container row border rounded border-danger boton">
        <div>
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/70/000000/java-coffee-cup-logo.png" alt="Logo">
          <a href="" class="ml-3">Programación</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container row border rounded border-danger boton">
        <div>
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/70/000000/networking-manager.png" alt="Logo">
          <a href="" class="ml-3">Redes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container row border rounded border-danger boton">
        <div>
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/70/000000/statistics.png" alt="Logo">
          <a href="" class="ml-3">Analisis</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="page-footer fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container row">
      <h3 class="col-4" style="font-size: 11px">Hora : 12:02:24</h3>
      <h3 class="col-8" style="font-size: 10px">@Copyright Universidad de Belgrano</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Si no quieres usar `fixed-bottom` porque no quieres las "ramificaciones" que trae el posicionamiento `fixed` (el pie se vería todo el tiempo, deberías añadir margen/padding al cuerpo de la página para que no se superponga el pie al contenido), puedes implementar otros métodos.

La página de Bootstrap contiene un [par de ejemplos con código específico](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) para que el pie de página se quede abajo del todo. Uno de ellos usa posición absolute y lo puedes ver [aquí](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/sticky-footer.css):

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```